# Post XML data with ASIFormDataRequest error

Tags: objective-c, xml, asiformdatarequest

> ```
> NSURL *postUrl =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mainString];
> ```

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:postUrl];
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [xmlString length]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:msgLength];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:contentType];
```

//    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];//Test For JSON is good
    [request appendPostData:theData];
    [request buildPostBody];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

```
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:20];// 测试连接的时间，默认10s
[postUrl release];
```

I get Nothing from the following code, which also does not produce an error.

```
(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSData *theData = [request responseData];
    NSString *ret = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"ret--------------%@",ret);
}
```

When I use JSON, I get the result.